# List all channel in Hyperledger Fabric network using NODE SDK

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

How can i get the list of all channels in an Hyperledger Fabric network?
*If not possible*, can i list all the channels that a particular organization has joined.
I know i can use the **[queryChannels](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/Client.html#queryChannels__anchor)** API of **Client** class to get the list of channel a particular peer has joined but i want to know about the channel name of all the peers in particular organization at least.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getChannelPeers](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/Channel.html#getChannelPeers__anchor) method after you got the channel list with `queryChannels`

```
    let result = await client.queryChannels(peer);

    result.channels.forEach(channel => {
        let channelName = channel.channel_id;
        let channelInstance = client.getChannel(channelName);

        let channelPeers = channel.getChannelPeers();
    });
```

Comment: I think my question is not clear. Suppose there is an organization Org1 has three peer (P1, P2, and P3) and there are four channel C1, C2, C3 and C4 in a network. P1 has joined channel C1, P2 has joined C2 and P3 has joined C3. Now i want to write an API such that i can get all channel name joined by peers of org1 (Here, answer is C1, C2 and C3)

Comment: hi @Sourav, I think you could reach your target by following these steps:

    (1) Get the list of Peer by using `client.getPeersForOrg(mspid)` method.

    (2) After you get the peer list, you can call `client.queryChannels(peer)` method for each peer in that list

Hope this can help you!